# Amazon S3 - MS office files corrupted when downloading

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-s3

When I upload a docx, xlsx or pptx to amazon S3 using aws .net sdk the file is getting uploaded fine and I am able to view the file directly from S3 without any issues. But when I download the file in ASP.net using C# I am getting a warning message (see below) when opening the file:

"Excel found unreadable content in test.xlsx. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook?" If I click yes, I am able to see all the contents in the document.

similarly I am getting a warning message for .docx file as well.

This is the C# code I am using:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.OutputStream.Write(Content, 0, Content.Length);
Response.Flush();

HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

**Update:** When I download the file in windows forms app it is working fine and the problem is with web app only.

What am I doing wrong?

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

More information is needed to figure this out. The code snippet you provided looks OK. The problem looks to be elsewhere in your code... For example, what are you loading inside "Content"?

Also, it would help if you tried uploading and downloading a simple text file, to see what kind of data gets appended.

Comment: The "Content" is nothing a byte[] and the problem happens only for the .docx, .xlsx & .pptx files, other files are seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If `Content` is a `byte[]` created from a `MemoryStream`, make sure you're calling [`.ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx) and not [`.GetBuffer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx) to get it.  If you use `.GetBuffer()`, you'll potentially get extra bytes on the end, which the office file format probably doesn't like.  Your other file types you've tried it with might be more tolerant of extra data they weren't expecting on the end.

Comment: Yes, I am using .ToArray() only.